# Regex to retrieve includes from classic ASP

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, asp-classic

I have a project to search 1400+ classic asp websites in search of all the places that we are passing usernames and passwords. In doing this I need to retrieve all of the includes as most of this logic is in an include. I have built a code crawler but am having a hard time coming-up with what seems to be a simple regex to return all the includes in a gives file.

The pattern is like this:

```
   <!--#include file="includes/headers.inc"-->
```

Could somebody please help me with this. I need something that will match this pattern and return everything between the

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything between what?

Comment: Sorry. Formatting dropped the "<!--#include" and "-->" for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var includes = new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex("#include\\W+file=\"([^\"]+)\"");
var matchResult = regex.Match(fileContent);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    includes.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```